# Running (starting) a flutter app with flask backend

Tags: python, flutter, dart, flask

I am very new to flutter and I am confused how I can start the app.
I downloaded several examples (e.g. https://github.com/ihassanjavaid/Iris-Predictor-Flutter-Flask) but I just don't know how to start it.
Having no flask in my flutter app I know I can use `flutter run`or `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=5000`.

If I had a pure flask app I would start it with `flask run`but having flask AND flutter I don't know what to do. When I try either of the said commands then either the flask stuff or the flutter stuff isn't running. Is there a way to start both at the same time?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to run both apps on same port i.e 5000. Start flutter app on 5001 and flask app on 5000

Comment: Including to what @DivakarPatil mentioned, also you might face some troubles with CORS issues. But first, get them started, then that can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should run Flask at different port e.g. change `flask run --port 5000` to `flask run --port 8000`. This way, your Flask app will run at port 8000 and won't interfere with Flutter port, which you set to 5000 using this command: `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=5000`
2. I assume, your Flutter app wants to request data from your Flask app. If it is so, you will have a lot of issues because of requesting due to Chrome's Security Policy